# Will threading improve performance?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a program set up like this. It is a .Net Framework 4 console app.
This program is used to gather the sc-bytes and cs-bytes from every log file (from the previous week) on each server. This program is finished, but takes a very long time to run.

```
foreach (string server in servers)
            {

                foreach (string website in Directory.GetDirectories(server))
                {

                    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(website))
                    {
```

I was just wondering if something like threading or PLINQ could be used to speed up the process?
If this would improve performance, I'm not sure of the best way to implement it because it seems illogical to have a new thread for each log file (or even each website) because having that many threads would obviously not improve performance.

If you need to see more code, please ask, but this program basically reads each line of each file that was created within the last seven days, adds the bytes numbers, and then uses directory entries to get the website name (from the ID), and then outputs the name and total bytes for each website into a text file (which will eventually be a database instead). 
I don't need any actual code, just advice on the best way (if possible) to improve performance.

Thanks.

Comment: A good idea might be to invest in a high end SSD. This will certainly improve the situation much more than multithreading your application

Comment: Your code doesn't really make any sense.  how are you getting files from a web site?

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I should have provided more code. Each server in my array of servers looks like ... servers.Add(@"\\1.1.1.1\e$\logfiles"); ... They all point directly to a log folder, and then I use Directory.GetFiles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an IO bound task like this (iterating over directories and files and reading them), the bottleneck is disk IO, not CPU.

Parallelizing (?) this is not likely to help with speeding it up and might even hurt performance.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Sorry I can't vote up your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If servers are disks on different machines then it would improve performance to parallelize request directories and files from each server. That is one server running in 1 thread and maybe 1000 servers running in 10 threads.  Your program will be waiting a lot for IO and network bandwidth might be the bottleneck.
A better approch would be to have a web service on each server performing the counting and then ask each web service for the results.  This way the network would not be the bottleneck and you might even make the web services in a way that they already know the answer when you ask them (Maybe using a file system watcher.)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the "processing" that is done whether using multiple concurrent threads will increase performance. Most likely from your description you are I/O bound, so multi-threading will not help much, or might even be worse.

So unless you measure it yourself, the answer is a definite "maybe". Measuring is key here.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Sorry I can't vote up your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on several things: how many CPUs the machine running the client program  has, whether the log-checking-per-server is getting right into the log folder on each server or is checking every directory on each server (and if so how big the file system is on the servers), and how deep the folders go in what is probably recursion through Directory.GetDirectories in your snip of code.

You said it take a "very long time" for this task to run. Some basic Perfmon statistics and some TaskManager views can help you determine how much the CPU and disks are being used *locally* as you collect the data, but I suspect not as much as you would think.

If you concurrently process the logs on multiple remote servers using .Net's System.Threading, you are likely to find the I/O load spreads out as I/O load across the various servers under the  multithreading.  Then the possible bottlenecks on the client machine trying to collect this data concurrently from different servers will be dictated by the number of CPUs the client machine has to multiprocess the threads and the network bandwidth it can provide to receive the answers across the network path to the various servers concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

The Filesystem caches access to data, especially things like directory and file information.  So, you should be able to see a light improvement on performance if you use things like PLINQ.  In a console app, I don't really see the point though.  If performance and the perception of performance was important, this sort of thing would be done in a GUI with progress and cancellation...

But, I think there's some question about the code you've posted.  Getting files from a web site?  That will require some sort of request over-the-wire to another server; I would suggest that operation be done async.  You haven't provided the detail for anyone to suggest how you'd do that though.

Comment: I'm not getting files from a website, it is from servers. Each server is set up with a log folder, which has a folder for each website inside. Each website folder contains the log files. I can provide more code if necessary.

Comment: You code detail both servers and websites...  It's not clear what you're trying to do; so, it may be difficult to give you advice.

Comment: Any mention of a website in my code is just a directory on a server, not an actual website. Here is an example path to a log file on a server >> \\216.18.234.20\e$\logfiles\W3SVC10\u_ex120603.log  ... Where W3SVC10 is the website I am referring to. It is just a folder containing logs.

Answer (score 0):

Paralleling makes sense only if performance of several threads is better than performance of one thread.

Actual result depends on hardware you have.

If you have very fast network and data is stored in SSDs in every server you may try to parallel all your processes.

configuration described above is rare case in real world.

In regular environment check your network utilization. If it is below 20% **you may try paralleling for servers**.

Sequential read is much faster with HDD (not SSD) comparing to multi-threaded read so paralleling  of nested loops unlikely will help you.

**P.S.** Do not try to utilize 100% of your network. Your IT will not be happy about that.