# C# I/O Parallelism does increase performance with SSD?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I've read some answers ( for [*example*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954340/will-threading-improve-performance))  here at SO where some say that parallelism is not going to increase performance ( maybe in read IO).

But I've created few tests which shows that also WRITE operations are much faster.

— **READ TEST:**

I've created random 6000 files with dummy data :

[image]

Let's try to read them w/ w/o parallelism :

```
var files =
    Directory.GetFiles("c:\\temp\\2\\", "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Take(1000).ToList();

    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    files.ForEach(f => ReadAllBytes(f).GetHashCode()); 
    sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump("Run READ- Serial");
    sw.Stop(); 


    sw.Restart();
    files.AsParallel().ForAll(f => ReadAllBytes(f).GetHashCode()); 
    sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump("Run READ- Parallel");
    sw.Stop();
```

Result1:

> Run READ- Serial 595
>
> Run READ- Parallel 193

Result2:

> Run READ- Serial
>   316
>
> Run READ- Parallel
>   192

— **WRITE TEST:**

Going to create 1000 random files where each file is 300K. (I've emptied the directory from prev test)

[image]

```
var bytes = new byte[300000];
Random r = new Random();
r.NextBytes(bytes);
var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).ToList();

sw.Restart();
list.ForEach((f) => WriteAllBytes(@"c:\\temp\\2\\" + Path.GetRandomFileName(), bytes)); 
sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump("Run WRITE serial");
sw.Stop();

sw.Restart();
list.AsParallel().ForAll((f) => WriteAllBytes(@"c:\\temp\\2\\" + 
Path.GetRandomFileName(), bytes)); 
sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump("Run  WRITE Parallel");
sw.Stop();
```

Result 1:

> Run WRITE serial 2028
>
> Run  WRITE Parallel 368

Result 2:

> Run WRITE serial 784
>
> Run  WRITE Parallel 426

**Question:**

The results have surprised me. It is clear that against all expectations ( especially with WRITE operations)-  the performance are better with parallelism , yet with IO operations.

How/Why come  the parallelism results  better  ? It seems that SSD can work with threads and that there is no/less bottleneck when running more than one job at a time in the IO device.

*Nb I didn't test it with HDD (I'll be happy that one that has HDD will run the tests.)*

Comment: Just to be sure, try inverting the test (first parallel, then non-parallel). There is a possibility Windows is caching some files after the first read.

Comment: @xanatos same correlation : https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvuCM.png

Comment: I can reproduce the result

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark this is the ssd http://ssd.userbenchmark.com/SpeedTest/2342/SAMSUNG-MZ7TD256HAFV-000L7

Comment: But what is so surprising in that? I thought it's a common knowledge that SSD can perform IO in parallel, which is part of why they are faster than HHD.

Comment: @evkto to me it wasn't understood

Comment: Benchmarking is a tricky art, you are just not measuring what you think you are. You are measure time to open file handle + file read + close file handle. Open file handle can take long time, but it can effectively be done in parallel.

Comment: Also, a stupid question, but have you checked disk utilization rate during the benchmarks? Any less than 100% means the drive is spending some of the time waiting idle.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Benchmarking is a tricky art, you are just not measuring what you think you are.  That it is not actually I/O overhead is somewhat obvious from the test results, why is the single threaded code faster the second time you run it?

What you are not counting on is the behavior of the *file system cache*.  It keeps a copy of the disk content in RAM.  This has a particularly big impact on the multi-threaded code measurement, it is not using any I/O *at all*.  In a nutshell:

- Reads come from RAM if the file system cache has a copy of the data.  This operates at memory bus speeds, typically around 35 gigabytes/second.  If it does not have a copy then the read is delayed until the disk supplies the data.  It does not just read the requested cluster but an entire cylinder worth of data off the disk.
- Writes go straight to RAM, completes *very* quickly.  That data is written to the disk lazily in the background while the program keeps executing, optimized to minimize write head movement in cylinder order.  Only if no more RAM is available will a write ever stall.

Actual cache size depends on the installed amount of RAM and the need for RAM imposed by running processes.  A very rough guideline is that you can count on 1GB on a machine with 4GB of RAM, 3GB on a machine with 8GB of RAM.  It is visible in Resource Monitor, Memory tab, displayed as the "Cached" value.  Keep in mind that it is highly variable.

So enough to make sense of what you see, the Parallel test benefits greatly from the Serial test already have read all the data.  If you had written the test so that the Parallel test was run first then you'd have gotten very different results.  Only if the cache is cold could you see the loss of perf due to threading.  You'd have to restart your machine to ensure that condition.  Or read another very large file first, large enough to evict useful data from the cache.

Only if you have a-priori knowledge of your program only ever reading data that was just written can you safely use threads without risking a perf loss.  That guarantee is normally pretty hard to come by.  It does exist, a good example is Visual Studio building your project.  The compiler writes the build result to the obj\Debug directory, then MSBuild copies it to bin\Debug.  Looks very wasteful, but it is not, that copy will always complete very quickly since the file is hot in the cache.  The cache also explains the difference between a cold and a hot start of a .NET program and why using NGen is not always best.

Comment: But still, can SSD achieve perfomance benefits from parallel writes\reads?

Comment: @Hans if so , Can you please explain the following ? : I've created 1000 different files , restarted the machine , read them serially  - then restarted again the machine , read them in parallel and still the parallel was much faster. Can you please explain this ?

Comment: Maybe it is time to conclude that you have a very nice SSD.  No idea what it does, technical info about the controllers is impossible to come by.  Having nice hardware is not exactly always beneficial on a dev machine btw, tends to not reproduce well on the user's machine.

Answer (score 9):

The reason of this behaviour is called **File Caching** which is a Windows feature to improve performance of file operations. Let`s have a look at a short explanation at the [Windows Dev Center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364218(v=vs.85).aspx):

> By default, Windows caches file data that is read from disks and
>   written to disks. This implies that read operations read file data
>   from an area in system memory known as the system file cache, rather
>   than from the physical disk.

This means the hard disk is (typically) never used during your tests.

We can avoid this behaviour by creating a `FileStream` using using the `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` flag, documented at the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx). Let's have a look at our new `ReadUnBuffered` function using this flag:

```
private static object ReadUnbuffered(string f)
{
    //Unbuffered read and write operations can only
    //be performed with blocks having a multiple
    //size of the hard drive sector size
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096 * 10];
    const ulong FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING = 0x20000000;
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(
        f,
        FileMode.Open,
        FileAccess.Read,
        FileShare.None,
        8,
        (FileOptions)FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING))
    {
        return fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
}
```

**The result:** Reading serial is much faster. In my case even nearly twice as fast.

Reading a file using the standard Windows cache has only to perform CPU and RAM operations to manage the chaching of files, deal with the `FileStream`, ... because the files are already cached. Sure, it's not very CPU-intensive but it's not negligible. Since the files are already in the system cache, the parallel approach (without cache modification) shows exactly the time of these *overhead* operations.

This behaviour can also be transfered to write operations.

Comment: The behaviour is the same. If file caching is active the data gets still cached in the RAM. This means no physical storage operation is done until there is no more RAM available (during write) or the file is not already cached (during read)

Comment: Please read my comments to Hans. even after restart , with different file ( each file is different) - results were better with parallel.

Comment: I think this is the CPU overhead needed to cache the files. Running parallel speeds up this process.

Answer (score 8):

It is a very interesting topic! I'm sorry that I can't explain the technical details, but there are some concerns need to be raised. It is a bit long, so I can't fit them into the comment. Please forgive me to post it into as an "answer".

I think you need to think about both large and small files, also, the test must run a few times and get the average time to make sure the result is verifiable. A general guideline is to run it 25 times as a paper in evolutionary computing suggests.

Another concern is about system caching. You only created one `bytes` buffer and always write the same thing, I don't know how the system handles buffer, but to minimise the difference, I would suggest you to create different buffer for different files.

(Update: maybe GC also affect the performance, so I revised again to put GC aside as much as I could.)

I luckily have both SSD and HDD on my computer, and revised the test code. I executed the it with different configurations and get the following results. Hope I can inspire someone for better explanation.

1KB, 256 Files

```
Avg Write Parallel SSD: 46.88
Avg Write Serial   SSD: 94.32
Avg Read  Parallel SSD: 4.28
Avg Read  Serial   SSD: 15.48
Avg Write Parallel HDD: 35.4
Avg Write Serial   HDD: 71.52
Avg Read  Parallel HDD: 4.52
Avg Read  Serial   HDD: 14.68
```

512KB, 256 Files

```
Avg Write Parallel SSD: 86.84
Avg Write Serial   SSD: 210.84
Avg Read  Parallel SSD: 65.64
Avg Read  Serial   SSD: 80.84
Avg Write Parallel HDD: 85.52
Avg Write Serial   HDD: 186.76
Avg Read  Parallel HDD: 63.24
Avg Read  Serial   HDD: 82.12
// Note: GC seems still kicked in the parallel reads on this test
```

My machine is:  i7-6820HQ / 32G / Windows 7 Enterprise x64 / VS2017 Professional / Target .NET 4.6 / Running in debug mode.

The two harddrives are:

C drive: IDE\Crucial_CT275MX300SSD4___________________M0CR021

D drive: IDE\ST2000LM003_HN-M201RAD__________________2BE10001

The revised code is as follows:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
string path;
int fileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
int numFiles = 2;

byte[] bytes = new byte[fileSize];
Random r = new Random(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Millisecond);
List<int> list = Enumerable.Range(0, numFiles).ToList();
List<List<byte>> allBytes = new List<List<byte>>(numFiles);

List<string> files;

int numTests = 1;

List<long> wss = new List<long>(numTests);
List<long> wps = new List<long>(numTests);
List<long> rss = new List<long>(numTests);
List<long> rps = new List<long>(numTests);

List<long> wsh = new List<long>(numTests);
List<long> wph = new List<long>(numTests);
List<long> rsh = new List<long>(numTests);
List<long> rph = new List<long>(numTests);

Enumerable.Range(1, numTests).ToList().ForEach((i) => {
    path = @"C:\SeqParTest\";

    allBytes.Clear();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
    list.ForEach((x) => { r.NextBytes(bytes); allBytes.Add(new List<byte>(bytes)); });
    try { GC.TryStartNoGCRegion(0, true); } catch (Exception) { }
    sw.Restart();
    list.AsParallel().ForAll((x) => File.WriteAllBytes(path + Path.GetRandomFileName(), allBytes[x].ToArray()));
    wps.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    sw.Stop();
    try { GC.EndNoGCRegion(); } catch (Exception) { }
    Debug.Print($"Write parallel SSD #{i}: {wps[i - 1]}");

    allBytes.Clear();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
    list.ForEach((x) => { r.NextBytes(bytes); allBytes.Add(new List<byte>(bytes)); });
    try { GC.TryStartNoGCRegion(0, true); } catch (Exception) { }
    sw.Restart();
    list.ForEach((x) => File.WriteAllBytes(path + Path.GetRandomFileName(), allBytes[x].ToArray()));
    wss.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    sw.Stop();
    try { GC.EndNoGCRegion(); } catch (Exception) { }
    Debug.Print($"Write serial   SSD #{i}: {wss[i - 1]}");

    files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Take(numFiles).ToList();
    try { GC.TryStartNoGCRegion(0, true); } catch (Exception) { }
    sw.Restart();
    files.AsParallel().ForAll(f => File.ReadAllBytes(f).GetHashCode());
    rps.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    sw.Stop();
    try { GC.EndNoGCRegion(); } catch (Exception) { }
    files.ForEach(f => File.Delete(f));
    Debug.Print($"Read  parallel SSD #{i}: {rps[i - 1]}");
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();

    files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Take(numFiles).ToList();
    try { GC.TryStartNoGCRegion(0, true); } catch (Exception) { }
    sw.Restart();
    files.ForEach(f => File.ReadAllBytes(f).GetHashCode());
    rss.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    sw.Stop();
    try { GC.EndNoGCRegion(); } catch (Exception) { }
    files.ForEach(f => File.Delete(f));
    Debug.Print($"Read  serial   SSD #{i}: {rss[i - 1]}");
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();

    path = @"D:\SeqParTest\";

    allBytes.Clear();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
    list.ForEach((x) => { r.NextBytes(bytes); allBytes.Add(new List<byte>(bytes)); });
    try { GC.TryStartNoGCRegion(0, true); } catch (Exception) { }
    sw.Restart();
    list.AsParallel().ForAll((x) => File.WriteAllBytes(path + Path.GetRandomFileName(), allBytes[x].ToArray()));
    wph.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    sw.Stop();
    try { GC.EndNoGCRegion(); } catch (Exception) { }
    Debug.Print($"Write parallel HDD #{i}: {wph[i - 1]}");

    allBytes.Clear();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
    list.ForEach((x) => { r.NextBytes(bytes); allBytes.Add(new List<byte>(bytes)); });
    try { GC.TryStartNoGCRegion(0, true); } catch (Exception) { }
    sw.Restart();
    list.ForEach((x) => File.WriteAllBytes(path + Path.GetRandomFileName(), allBytes[x].ToArray()));
    wsh.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    sw.Stop();
    try { GC.EndNoGCRegion(); } catch (Exception) { }
    Debug.Print($"Write serial   HDD #{i}: {wsh[i - 1]}");

    files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Take(numFiles).ToList();
    try { GC.TryStartNoGCRegion(0, true); } catch (Exception) { }
    sw.Restart();
    files.AsParallel().ForAll(f => File.ReadAllBytes(f).GetHashCode());
    rph.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    sw.Stop();
    try { GC.EndNoGCRegion(); } catch (Exception) { }
    files.ForEach(f => File.Delete(f));
    Debug.Print($"Read  parallel HDD #{i}: {rph[i - 1]}");
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();

    files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Take(numFiles).ToList();
    try { GC.TryStartNoGCRegion(0, true); } catch (Exception) { }
    sw.Restart();
    files.ForEach(f => File.ReadAllBytes(f).GetHashCode());
    rsh.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    sw.Stop();
    try { GC.EndNoGCRegion(); } catch (Exception) { }
    files.ForEach(f => File.Delete(f));
    Debug.Print($"Read  serial   HDD #{i}: {rsh[i - 1]}");
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
});

Debug.Print($"Avg Write Parallel SSD: {wps.Average()}");
Debug.Print($"Avg Write Serial   SSD: {wss.Average()}");
Debug.Print($"Avg Read  Parallel SSD: {rps.Average()}");
Debug.Print($"Avg Read  Serial   SSD: {rss.Average()}");

Debug.Print($"Avg Write Parallel HDD: {wph.Average()}");
Debug.Print($"Avg Write Serial   HDD: {wsh.Average()}");
Debug.Print($"Avg Read  Parallel HDD: {rph.Average()}");
Debug.Print($"Avg Read  Serial   HDD: {rsh.Average()}");
```

Well, I haven't fully tested the code, so it may buggy. I realised it sometimes stops on the parallel read, I assume it was because of the deletion of files from sequential read was completed AFTER reading the list of existing files in the next step, so it complains file not found error.

Another problem is that I used the newly created files for read test. Theoretically it is better to not do so (even restart computer / fill out empty space on SSD to avoid caching), but I didn't bother because the intended comparison is between sequential and parallel performance.

Update:

I don't know how to explain the reason, but I think it may because the IO resource is pretty idle? I'll try two things the next:

1. Large files (1GB) in serial / parallel
2. When other background activities using disk IO.

Update 2:

Some results from large files (512M, 32 files):

```
Write parallel SSD #1: 140935
Write serial   SSD #1: 133656
Read  parallel SSD #1: 62150
Read  serial   SSD #1: 43355
Write parallel HDD #1: 172448
Write serial   HDD #1: 138381
Read  parallel HDD #1: 173436
Read  serial   HDD #1: 142248

Write parallel SSD #2: 122286
Write serial   SSD #2: 119564
Read  parallel SSD #2: 53227
Read  serial   SSD #2: 43022
Write parallel HDD #2: 175922
Write serial   HDD #2: 137572
Read  parallel HDD #2: 204972
Read  serial   HDD #2: 142174

Write parallel SSD #3: 121700
Write serial   SSD #3: 117730
Read  parallel SSD #3: 107546
Read  serial   SSD #3: 42872
Write parallel HDD #3: 171914
Write serial   HDD #3: 145923
Read  parallel HDD #3: 193097
Read  serial   HDD #3: 142211

Write parallel SSD #4: 125805
Write serial   SSD #4: 118252
Read  parallel SSD #4: 113385
Read  serial   SSD #4: 42951
Write parallel HDD #4: 176920
Write serial   HDD #4: 137520
Read  parallel HDD #4: 208123
Read  serial   HDD #4: 142273

Write parallel SSD #5: 116394
Write serial   SSD #5: 116592
Read  parallel SSD #5: 61273
Read  serial   SSD #5: 43315
Write parallel HDD #5: 172259
Write serial   HDD #5: 138554
Read  parallel HDD #5: 275791
Read  serial   HDD #5: 142311

Write parallel SSD #6: 107839
Write serial   SSD #6: 135071
Read  parallel SSD #6: 79846
Read  serial   SSD #6: 43328
Write parallel HDD #6: 176034
Write serial   HDD #6: 138671
Read  parallel HDD #6: 218533
Read  serial   HDD #6: 142481

Write parallel SSD #7: 120438
Write serial   SSD #7: 118032
Read  parallel SSD #7: 45375
Read  serial   SSD #7: 42978
Write parallel HDD #7: 173151
Write serial   HDD #7: 140579
Read  parallel HDD #7: 176492
Read  serial   HDD #7: 142153

Write parallel SSD #8: 108862
Write serial   SSD #8: 123556
Read  parallel SSD #8: 120162
Read  serial   SSD #8: 42983
Write parallel HDD #8: 174699
Write serial   HDD #8: 137619
Read  parallel HDD #8: 204069
Read  serial   HDD #8: 142480

Write parallel SSD #9: 111618
Write serial   SSD #9: 117854
Read  parallel SSD #9: 51224
Read  serial   SSD #9: 42970
Write parallel HDD #9: 173069
Write serial   HDD #9: 136936
Read  parallel HDD #9: 159978
Read  serial   HDD #9: 143401

Write parallel SSD #10: 115381
Write serial   SSD #10: 118545
Read  parallel SSD #10: 79509
Read  serial   SSD #10: 43818
Write parallel HDD #10: 179545
Write serial   HDD #10: 138556
Read  parallel HDD #10: 167978
Read  serial   HDD #10: 143033

Write parallel SSD #11: 113105
Write serial   SSD #11: 116849
Read  parallel SSD #11: 84309
Read  serial   SSD #11: 42620
Write parallel HDD #11: 179432
Write serial   HDD #11: 139014
Read  parallel HDD #11: 219161
Read  serial   HDD #11: 142515

Write parallel SSD #12: 124901
Write serial   SSD #12: 121769
Read  parallel SSD #12: 137192
Read  serial   SSD #12: 43144
Write parallel HDD #12: 176091
Write serial   HDD #12: 139042
Read  parallel HDD #12: 214205
Read  serial   HDD #12: 142576

Write parallel SSD #13: 110896
Write serial   SSD #13: 123152
Read  parallel SSD #13: 56633
Read  serial   SSD #13: 42665
Write parallel HDD #13: 173123
Write serial   HDD #13: 138514
Read  parallel HDD #13: 210003
Read  serial   HDD #13: 142215

Write parallel SSD #14: 117762
Write serial   SSD #14: 126865
Read  parallel SSD #14: 90005
Read  serial   SSD #14: 44089
Write parallel HDD #14: 172958
Write serial   HDD #14: 139908
Read  parallel HDD #14: 217826
Read  serial   HDD #14: 142216

Write parallel SSD #15: 109912
Write serial   SSD #15: 121276
Read  parallel SSD #15: 72285
Read  serial   SSD #15: 42827
Write parallel HDD #15: 176255
Write serial   HDD #15: 139084
Read  parallel HDD #15: 183926
Read  serial   HDD #15: 142111

Write parallel SSD #16: 122476
Write serial   SSD #16: 126283
Read  parallel SSD #16: 47875
Read  serial   SSD #16: 43799
Write parallel HDD #16: 173436
Write serial   HDD #16: 137203
Read  parallel HDD #16: 294374
Read  serial   HDD #16: 142387

Write parallel SSD #17: 112168
Write serial   SSD #17: 121079
Read  parallel SSD #17: 79001
Read  serial   SSD #17: 43207
```

I regret I don't have time to complete all 25 runs, but the result shows on large files the sequential R/W could be faster than parallel if the disk usage is full. I think it may the reason of other discussions on SO.

Comment: So how do you explain that also with HDD - (non ssd) it works faster ?

Comment: @Royi, I don't know yet. I will do more test if I have time. But I think it relates to some bottleneck of IO, IDE/SATA bandwidth and IOPS/Seektime. The gut thought is that the IOPS/Seektime should be the bottleneck. However, from the test, it seems not the case. Maybe some more calculation can tell but I need some more time. Sorry.

Comment: You are still using GetHashCode, which is very likely to at least some degree benefit from running in parallell. Your code ReadAllBytes(f).GetHashCode()) means "read file from disk to memory - read the content from memory", meaning your disk is idle while calculating the hash code in the serial mode. In parallel mode, disk can be read while the hashcode is calculated for another file. Not sure this factor is significant or not, but it is there.

Comment: Additionally, NCQ as mentioned in a different answer is a feature supported by many spinning drives as well. This could be a reason for the improvement in parallell mode. You could try looking for a way to disable NCQ and see if there is a difference.

Comment: I tried to run large files overnight, but haven't fully completed. I am in training all week so don't have to update. Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

First, the test needs to exclude any CPU/RAM operations (GetHashCode) since the serial code may be waiting for the CPU before doing the next disk operation.

Internally, an SSD is always trying to parallellize operations between its different internal chips. Its ability to do so depends on the model, how much (TRIMmed) free space it has etc. Until some time ago, this should behave the same in parallell and serial, because the queue between the OS and the SSD is serial anyway..... Unless the SSD supports NCQ (Native Command Queue), which enables the SSD to select which operation from the queue to do next, in order to maximize the usage of all its chips. So what you are seeing could be the benefits of NCQ. (Note that NCQ also works for hard disk drives).

Due to the differences between SSDs (controller strategy, number of internal chips, free space etc) the benefits of parallellization will probably vary a lot.