# Java: Read 10,000 excel files and write to 1 master file in Java using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, multithreading, apache-poi

I searched in Google but couldn't find a proper answer for my problem mentioned below. Pardon me if this is a duplicate question, but I couldn't find any proper answer.

So, coming to the question. I have to read multiple Excel files in Java and generate a final Excel report file out of these multiple files.

There are 2 folders:

1. Source folder: It contains multiple Excel file (Probably 10,000 files)
2. Destination folder: This folder will have one final Master Excel file after reading all the files from Source folder.

For each Excel file read from Source folder, the master file in the Destination folder will have 1 row each.

I am planning to use Apache POI to read and write excel files in Java.

I know its easy to read and write files in Java using POI, but my question is, given this scenario where there are almost 10,000 files to read and write into 1 single Master file, what will be the best approach to do that, considering the time taken and the CPU used by the program. Reading 1 file at a time will be too much time consuming.

So, I am planning to use threads to process files in batches of say 100 files at a time. Can anybody please point me to some resources or suggest me on how to proceed with this requirement?

Edited:

I have already written the program to read and write the file using POI. The code for the same is mentioned below:

```
        // Loop through the directory, fetching each file.
    File sourceDir = new File("SourceFolder");
    System.out.println("The current directory is = "+sourceDir);

    if(sourceDir.exists()) {
        if(sourceDir.isDirectory()){
            String[] filesInsideThisDir = sourceDir.list();
            numberOfFiles = filesInsideThisDir.length;
            for(String filename : filesInsideThisDir){
                System.out.println("(processFiles) The file name to read is = "+filename);

                // Read each file
                readExcelFile(filename);

                // Write the data
                writeMasterReport();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("(processFiles) Source directory specified is not a directory.");
        }
    } else {
    }
```

Here, the SourceFolder contains all the Excel files to read. I am looping through this folder fetching 1 file at a time, reading the contents and then writing to 1 Master Excel file.

The readExcelFile() method is reading every excel file, and creating a List which contains the data for each row to be written to Master excel file.

The writeMasterReport() method is writing the data read from every excel file.

The program is running fine. My question is, is there any way I can optimize this code by using Threads for reading through the files? I know that there is only 1 file to write to, and it cannot be done parallely. If the sourceFolder contains 10,000 files, reading and writing this way will take a lot of time to execute.

The size of each Input file will be around few hundred KB.

So, my question is, can we use Threads to read the files in batches, say 100 or 500 files per thread, and then write the data for each thread? I know the write part will need to be synchronized. This way at least the read and write time will be minimized. Please let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: Try it first and come back if you *really* have a problem with performance. Don't optimize prematurely.

Comment: "I am planning to use threads to process files in batches of say 100 files at a time." And then writing into the one destination workbook from all those threads? Not possible, see [FAQ 20. Can I access/modify workbooks/documents/slideshows in multiple threads?](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10224).

Comment: How long do you have to process these files? I'm guessing you don't need it done "instantly". Sometimes just chugging through them one-by-one is going to be sufficient.

Comment: lexicore is right, multithreading might complicate application unnecessarily and processing time improvment might be not worth it. You should first try to solve this problem with one thread and see if time is satysfing. Then you can try to transform your code to support many threads. How big are those excel files? If they are around a few mbs then it's most likely not worth it.

Comment: "For each Excel file read from Source folder, the master file in the Destination folder will have 1 row each.": Then collect the rows in `List` of `POJO`s first. This can be multi threaded. Then do writing the destination workbook from that `List` in one thread.

Comment: @lexicore.. I have already written the code to read and write. Please see my edit.

Comment: @AndyTurner...I am reading and writing the files one by one..

Comment: @MichaelDz.. Each file will be around few hundred KB's. But then 10,000 files will be a huge number of file to process. So any idea if Multithreading can help here or 1 thread will be okay?

Comment: @AxelRichter..I am also planning to first read all the files at a time using Threads and then finally write the file. The problem will be that I will need to synchronize the reading part. Can you please let me know how to proceed with that?

Comment: @user1302909 Please re-read my comment above. At the moment there is no indication that you actually have a performance problem. You *think* there should be but is there, really? How long does your code run? What are your requirements, how long should the code run?

Comment: there is another concern on attempting to use multi threading (if it looks required). Since you are merging multiple files, does order in which files are merged matter. Also the rows of individual files will get mixed up if you use multi-threading and synchronize while writing. Please think through the problem statement and optimize when you find bottlenecks.

Answer (score 0):

With 10k of files ~100Kb each we're talking about reading ca. ~1Gb of data. If the processing is not overly complex (seems so) then your bottleneck will be IO.

So it most probably does not make sense to parallelize reading and processing files as IO has an upper limit.
Parallelizing would have made sense if processing were complex/the bottleneck. It does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: "processing files as IO has an upper limit." - can you please explain this?

Comment: @user1302909 Since files are on the disk, reading these files will be limited by the read speed of the disk. Assuming a "normal" SSD drive, you'll get read speed at probably around 0.5Gb/s ([source](https://www.lifewire.com/what-are-read-and-write-speeds-2640236)). [Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44456945/303810) indicate that parallel reading is not much (only 25% or so) faster than serial reading for 256x512Kb files. It is limited by the read speed of the drive.

Comment: @user1302909 Also you are limited by your writing speed. However theoretically fast you may read, writes when synchronized will not give you much performance benefit.